# Util logging doesn't delete old log files on rotation

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I used the below code to configure my logging.

```
public Boolean configureLogPath(String logPath, String level, String logComponents, int logFileSize,
        int logFileCount) {
    int logFileSizeInKbs = logFileSize * 1000;
    Boolean result = false;
    String[] splitComponents = logComponents.split(",");
    for (String component : splitComponents) {
        loggableComponents.add(component);
    }
    switch (level) {
    case "info":
        LOGGER.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        break;
    case "severe":
        LOGGER.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
        break;
    case "debug":
        LOGGER.setLevel(Level.CONFIG);
        break;
    case "off":
        LOGGER.setLevel(Level.OFF);
        break;
    default:
        LOGGER.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
    }
    try {
        simpleFormatter = new SimpleFormatter();
        logFileHandler = new FileHandler(logPath, logFileSizeInKbs, logFileCount);
        logFileHandler.setFormatter(simpleFormatter);
        LOGGER.setFilter(filter);

        LOGGER.addHandler(logFileHandler);
        result = true;
    } catch (SecurityException e1) {
        result = false;
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Security exception when reading log file" + e1);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        result = false;
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "IO Exception when reading log file" + e1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But though I have given the relevant parameters in the FileHandler for the logs to be rotated, the old log files still remain. Is this a behavior of util logging or is there anything I can do to remove old files during rotation?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a behavior of util logging or is there anything I can do to remove old files during rotation?

Per the FileHandler [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html):

> For a rotating set of files, as each file reaches a given size
>   limit, it is closed, rotated out, and a new file opened.

If you want to delete rotated files then simply don't rotate.  The goal of rotation is so that you can read old log data.

If you really want to rotate and delete old files you can override the [FileHandler.setOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/StreamHandler.html#setOutputStream-java.io.OutputStream-) method to listen for the rotation and write your own delete method.

```
private boolean constructed;
@Override
protected synchronized void setOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws SecurityException {
    super.setOutputStream(out);
    if (constructed && Level.OFF.equals(super.getLevel())) { //Rotating...
         deleteRotatedFiles();
    }
    constructed = true;
}
```

Comment: Won't this if condition delete the files if I manually turn off the logs? That is if my logs still haven't reached the rotation quantity and if I want to stop the logging I would set the log level of current logs to "Off". So won't this delete the log that is currently being used?

Comment: For a newly constructed FileHandler it would.  That is not too hard to work around as you can set the level to 2147483646 instead of OFF.  Or the FileHandler could be modified track that it is not the first call.